# Literal or expression to create an object with a string-valued property name

Tags: javascript, object

The following code creates an object in which the property name is set at runtime:

```
let pn = "xyz", ob = {}
op[pn] = 999
```

Is there any way to do that in a single step, as either a literal or an expression, and avoid the explicit assignment?

```
let pn = "xyz", ob = { <clever stuff goes in here> }
```

[Obviously I could write my own function, but where's the fun in that?]

Answer (score 0):

How about that by just using brackets `[]`?

```js
/*
// old way :)
let pn = "xyz", ob = {}
ob[pn] = 999
console.log(ob)
*/

//clever stuff goes here :)
let pn = "xyz", ob = { [pn]:999 }
console.log(ob)
```

Comment: Thanks: but pn is just a temporary and not needed, so I assume you could omit it?

Answer (score 0):

You can define key with in the object like this

```
 let obj={[pn="Xyz"]:999}
 console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Thanks: but pn is just a temporary and not needed, so I assume you could omit it?

Comment: Am I right in saying this is new in ES2015? See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer.